# How do I convert a javascript file into a wrapper function and use it in a html page?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a json file which stores product items. I need to render these items to `index.html` using pure javascript. So, I create a javascript file and used `fetch...then` to get json items one by one like this:- 
 
**store.js**

```
fetch("./data.json")
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    const allItemContainer = document.getElementById("all-items");

    data.pizza.forEach((item) => {
         //creating elements/div here for each item
   });
});
```

My html where I'm rendering this is something like this:-

```
    <body>
        <div id="all-items" class="shop-items"></div>
        <script src="store.js"></script>
    </body>
```

I want to use a wrapper function to store everything that I have in `store.js` and call it in `index.html` using `document.onload` or something like it. I'm planning to use wrapper function as it will avoid overwriting conflicts.

```
[
  {
    name: "Tandoori Pizza",
    price: "Rs.200",
  },
  {
    name: "Veggie Supreme",
    price: "Rs.250",
  },
  {
    name: "Veg Exotica",
    price: "Rs.300",
  },
  {
    name: "Chicken Pepper Crunch",
    price: "Rs.400",
  },
]
```

How do I do it? Can someone provide with a snippet?

Comment: what is JSON struture and what type of HTML element do you want to create?

Comment: as `fetch` is an ASYNC function so it will create element after every other JS code get executed, So why would you want to create a wrapper function.

Comment: `forEach` on array and Create HTML element in `then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `forEach` on the elements on the `then` block and use `appendChild` to append on the list.

```js
window.onload = (function runOnLoad() {
  const array = [{
      name: "Tandoori Pizza",
      price: "Rs.200",
    },
    {
      name: "Veggie Supreme",
      price: "Rs.250",
    },
    {
      name: "Veg Exotica",
      price: "Rs.300",
    },
    {
      name: "Chicken Pepper Crunch",
      price: "Rs.400",
    },
  ];
  const allItems = document.querySelector("#all-items");

  return () => {
    array.forEach((el) => {
      const element = document.createElement("div");
      const heading = document.createElement("h1");
      heading.textContent = el.name;

      const para = document.createElement("p");
      para.textContent = el.price;

      element.appendChild(heading);
      element.appendChild(para);

      allItems.appendChild(element);
    });
  };
})();
```

```html
<div id="all-items" class="shop-items"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but I wanted the above code in a wrapper function which I can use in the index.html by document.onLoad(). Is it possible to do it that way?

Comment: @NehaChaudhary yeah it is possible. Updated code. Is this what you want?

Comment: Ohh.. It seems simple enough. I'm actually new to this. I was thinking about something related to IIFE.

Comment: we can also do it with IIFE.

Comment: Could you please show it with IIFE as well? I'm unable to understand how I'm supposed to do it.

Comment: @NehaChaudhary Updated code, Now you may be confused why I've returned the function from the IIFE. It is because we've to assign a function to `window.onload` and when IIFE runs it will returns a function and gets executed. 

we can still access the variable `allItems` still inside the function because of the closure. Hope it will help. 

Comment: window.onload -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230814/discussion-between-decpk-and-neha-chaudhary).